# Errors in the Class Main of Microservices gateway application generated by Jhipster

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-boot, jhipster

Please I generated an application gateway using Jhipster. I just followed this Tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nnkxLSJcFLQ.

But when I open it in the Intelli Idea IDE. many errors will appear.

Please the ones who know, What should I do.

[Issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1k4Ow.png)

Comment: these are rather basic java issues, are you sure you are ready for microservices additional complexity?

Answer (score 1):

You must configure a jdk 8 in your IDEA project as you have errors for basic java types like java.util.Arrays, this is what your IDE tells you in the yellow bar. Also before that, make sure that you can run maven without errors in a shell.